# How to get the paragraph inside a contenteditable div that has the caret?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, contenteditable

I have a contenteditable div. I want to style with a border the paragraph **inside** the div which the user is currently editing.

How can I find the p inside the currently-edited div with jquery or javascript?

Comment: post a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: You can style the div using `div:focus`, but I don't think you can use CSS to determine which `p` is being edited unless you make them individually `contenteditable`.